# Why I am not Getting any Error here ? (In react app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am new to react

*index.js*

```
// import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import 'tachyons';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Card/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

*Card.js*

```
// import React from "react";
const Card = ()=>{
    return(
        <div>
          <h1>I am A Card </h1>
        </div>
    );
}
   
export default Card;
```

as in both the file I commented `// import React from 'react';`

but `<Card/>`(in index.js) and `<div><h1>I am A Card </h1></div>` (in Card.js)
which later turn into `React.createElement();` function call

which requires `React` which I already commented so it should give me an error  `'React' is not defined no-undef` but I am not getting any error here why.

Comment: Because that's no longer what it's transformed to: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html